# Are the topology of a manifold and the topology induced by the metric of a manifold the same?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I am just learning what a topology is and from what I have understood up till now is  that a topological space is nothing but a set with a notion of nearness that is given introducing open sets.

Ok, so, in the definition of manifold that I have seen (in Wald's general relativity book) a manifold is constructed mapping subsets of the manifold to be set with open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This way we introduce a topology in our manifold to be, since we can use the notion of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to define open balls of the manifold and hence we get a topology.

Now, we can add more structure to the manifold endowing it with a metric and making it a metric space.

Now my question. I know that a metric induces naturally a topology. But we already had a topology before itroducing the metric structure, so, are this two topologies the same topology?

Comment: Doesn't it matter if the metric is a riemannian one or a lorentzian one?

Comment: Of course, the metric must be Riemannian. You don't get a metric space otherwise.

Comment: in place of a riemmanian metric you could (as is done in general relativity) define a pseudo-riemmanian metric right?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. In a pseudo-Riemannian metric there can be distinct points that are distance zero apart, which cannot happen in a metric space.

Comment: so what you are saying is that a pseudo-Riemannian metric structure does not induce a topology right?

Comment: It doesn't induce a *metric* topology, since it's not Hausdorff.

Comment: In terms of pseudo-Riemannian manifolds, you may be interested in the [Alexandrov topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_topology#Alexandrov_topology).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the Riemannian case this is surely true, you may find it in "Foundations of Differential Geometry" by Kobayashi and Nomizu, volume 1, page 166, proposition 3.5.

In the pseudo-Riemannian case this is not true as indicated in a comment above by Zhen Lin (the topology induced by the pseudometric will no longer be Hausdorff, for instance).